# Resteasy multiple objects request

Tags: java, xml, resteasy

Does anyone know if it's possible to get multiples objects as parameters request using xml in resteasy? Something like this.

The function

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public String doSomething(Student student, Teacher teacher) {
    //Do something
    return result;
}
```

The classes

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Student {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private Date birthDate;

    //Getters and Setters
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Teacher {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String dept;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

XML I'm sending to server

```
<student>
    <name>Name</name>
    <birthDate>date</birthDate>
</student>
<teacher>
    <name>Name</name>
    <dept>date</dept>
</teacher>
```

I can get the correct values if the function have only one parameter. But if I try to receiver two or more, just the first object is correctly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the XML you are trying to send is invalid. You must have one root element. 
So you could group your student and teacher under a single element - and at that point in your `doSomething` method you will only have one object.

Comment: So, the solution is to create an aux class with student and teacher objects? Or resteasy have any anotation to do this? I tried @Wrapped, but it only works with arrays

Comment: Again depends how "restful" you want to be. You need to understand what "Resource" you are acting on and what action you are performing. Hard to say what you should do unless you describe what doSomething is.